# Reading selected value of dropdown list in HTML by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read the value of the selectedID in a drop down list in html through jQuery but it keeps producing an error. Did I miss something?

```
<select style="width: 80px;" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="metaList">
<option value="4d5e3a8c418416ea16000000">Wikipedia</option>  
<option value="4d5e3a8c418416ea16010000">Twitter</option>  
<option value="4d5e3a8c418416ea16020000">DBPedia</option>  
<option value="4d64cd534184162629000000">test</option>          
</select>
```

I tried which used to work before

```
var temp = $("#metaList").val();
```

but it produces NULL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function call is correct, but nothing is selected. That is the reason why `NULL` is returned.

Comment: Oh! Guess what, Yes and No!
I was selecting but I had two lists with the same id! So it was looking at the old one. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: First option of select list is always being selected by default

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var temp = $("#metaList option:selected").val();
```